# What's the best way of sharing object across containers?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

In one of my project I came across a situation where I want to create in-memory indices of objects. The primary index may use a different key and secondary indices would use some other elements as keys.
If I am using `std::map` for primary index as

```
std::map<string, Object>
```

then *which's the best way to store reference/pointer for the secondary index using another container (again std::map for instance considering all the Objects are unique) without making additional copies of the Object*?

- Using raw pointers or references which pose the risk of dangling pointers or references (I know that ideally when Object gets deleted from primary index, care should also be taken to remove it from secondary index but would the pointers/references in secondary indices invalidate when container for primary index adjust itself internally?)

  `std::map<string, const Object*>`
- Or using combination of shared_ptr's in primary index and weak_ptr's secondary index
  `std::map<string, std::shared_ptr<Object>> // primary index
  std::map<string, std::weak_ptr<Object>> // secondary index`

I know there are pros and cons for both the approaches. Especially I don't want to lose the flexibility of directly inserting the objects in the primary container but I also do not want the secondary index to copy the Objects again. The difficulty in using smart pointers just for secondary index is that they would not own the Object.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: How about using the primary key to reference the object? `std::map<string, string> // secondary index, value is primary key`. Disadvantage to this is you need another map look up to get the object. : P

Comment: May be multi-step references to Object? The cost will almost double.

Comment: I suggest using smart pointers to the objects.  Place pointers in an `std::vector`.  Next, create indices, e.g. `std::map`, using a key and a smart pointer to the object.

Comment: @ChadwickRobbert: Use a hash map and you still have constant cost. Also, will you notice this cost? And more importantly, once the profiler says you're spending too much time doing these lookups, is it easy to change to a different solution that takes some shortcuts? Probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your objects in some container. Depending on the frequency of additions / deletions of objects you may want to consider using a container that does not invalidate references to its elements, like a `std::list` or a `std::deque`.

Then, for your maps, just reference the objects (or any of their members) using references, i.e. using `std::reference_wrapper`.

Encapsulate the backend storage as well as the indices so that whenever you add or remove objects you remove invalid references from the indices as well as add any new references.

That way you only have to store your objects once and get around using smart pointers. This will obviously only work if you actually own the objects and control their lifetimes, and if you can keep the indices encapsulated (in order to keep them updated).